# jQuery event.fromElement alternative for Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events

I'm working with the `fromElement` property within my event callback and just realized it's not supported by Firefox (it returns undefined).

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4bQX/)

```
$('#test').on('mouseover', function(ev) {
    console.log(ev.fromElement);
});
```

Are there any alternatives?
For my purposes I need to know on which element the mouse previously was.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, use the properties that jQuery cares to normalize. `relatedTarget` is one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the jQuery event object has a `relatedTarget` property that should be cross-browser:

```
ev.relatedTarget
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/event.relatedtarget/

`fromElement` is a microsoft original, but w3 added `relatedTarget` to the specs. Read more here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#relatedtarget

Comment: Ah I used relatedTarget already for my `mouseout`event but didn't know that it also indicates the exited element for `mouseover` events. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete David's answer, when using `mouseleave` event, the `event.relatedTarget` has a different element returned to it:

> The **EventTarget** the pointing device entered to

For this situation, the better approach is to use `event.target`, because it returns:

> The **EventTarget** the pointing device exited from

More info about `event.relatedTarget` differences between event listeners can be found at [MDN MouseEvent.relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget)